# Creating a custom design-time collection editor in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, custom-controls, design-time, visual-studio-designer

I want to have a custom collection editor dialog in WPF (to edit a collection property on a custom control at design time) preferably by extending the exiting one , but I cannot find the existing one anywhere ...
I am looking for advanced customization (not just adding items in the collection editor's combo-box) like implementing an winforms-like editor for the treeview in wpf
Can anyone point me in the right direction?
Is there any other way I can achieve a goal like that (implementing the winforms design-time editor)
Here are the 2 editors
Wpf editor : [image: Wpf editor]

And Win forms editor
[image: Winforms editor]
You will notice that the wpf editor dose not show an items hierarchy , this is the feature I am intrested in most , I would like to see the hierarchy as I am editing the tree.

Comment: How does the design-time editor look like?

Comment: I am talking about making the normal(default) design-time editor for the treeview in WPF look like the normal(default) design-time editor for the same control(TreeView) but in windows forms environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use something like the PropertyGrid in the WPF Extended Toolkit?
http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PropertyGrid

You would implement it like this:

```
<extToolkit:PropertyGrid x:Name="_propertyGrid" Width="450" Margin="10" AutoGenerateProperties="False">
    <!-- Only the following properties will be displayed in the PropertyGrid -->
    <extToolkit:PropertyGrid.PropertyDefinitions>
        <extToolkit:PropertyDefinition Name="FirstName" />
        <extToolkit:PropertyDefinition Name="FavoriteColor" />
        <extToolkit:PropertyDefinition Name="PetNames" />
    </extToolkit:PropertyGrid.PropertyDefinitions>
</extToolkit:PropertyGrid>
```

Comment: Glad to help. That library is pretty awesome. You might find other really useful controls in there. I use at least 4 of them.